# Angular SPA and OAuth2 IdentityServer4 inside Docker

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have an Angular SPA Client. An Api as Resource Server to serve SPA and a IdentityServer4 as OAuth2. All of them inside a docker.

Angular is using angular-oauth2-oidc plugin.

The problem is with the issuer uri and Angular or Resource Server. Because docker, the ID4 Server get another name instead localhost:5000. e.g sso:5000.

So when the Angular try to load discover document, an error occurs: The issuer is invalid.

If the issuer uri is changed at IdentityServer Configuration Options, so the Resource Server cannot validate JWT Token, because Resource server doesn't know the URI localhost:5000.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    database:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "@Password1"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        ports:
            - "44274:1433"
    sso:
        image: "jpproject/v1"
        build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: sso.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        depends_on:
            - database
        environment: 
            SQLSERVER_CONNECTION: "Server=database,1433;Initial Catalog=JpProject;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=@Password1;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
            ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
            ISSUER_URI: "http://localhost:5000"
    user-management-api:
        build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: user-management.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5003:5003"
        depends_on:
            - database
            - sso
        environment: 
            SQLSERVER_CONNECTION: "Server=database,1433;Initial Catalog=JpProject;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=@Password1;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
            ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
            AUTHORITY: "http://localhost:5000"
    user-management-ui:
        container_name: user-management-ui
        build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: ui-user-management.dockerfile
        ports:
            - 4200:80
```

There is a way to tell docker use localhost instead hostname. Or a best way to have the same issuer uri between Api's and SPA.

Comment: Use ISSUER_URI from configuration i.e., `services.AddIdentityServer(x => x.IssuerUri = Configuration["ISSUER_URI"])`

Comment: Changing the issuer_uri will break the Resource Server. It'll can't validate JWT tokens, because inside the docker network the ID4 Server URI is different from outside (localhost:5000)

Comment: For those that get stucked in the same point. The offcial Admin UI uses dockers, to accomplish that. It add a new entry at hosts.
For example:

127.0.0.1 ids

Ids will be the same name of docker Image. Then change the other application AuthorityUri for http://ids/5000.